# Help explain the math behind this high-side current limiting circuit

Tags: current, current-limiting

I was playing around with my first attempt at building a high side current limiting circuit.  I was expecting a lot of trial and error to get anything functional, but low and behold my first try worked pretty well.  The circuit below limits the current to about 16 mA.  Can anyone explain how it works mathematically?  What if I wanted to have it limit to 30 mA?  I'm sure I could swap out some resistors and get it working for 30 mA, but I was hoping I could get a deeper understanding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I will do that in the future.  I wasn't simulating this circuit, I built it and tested with a multimeter.

Comment: Interestingly, if I try to simulate the circuit, it says that no current should be flowing.

Comment: You are "lucky" that this circuit "works" but wonder how you decided that is works because in my opinion **it is not a proper current source circuit**. In a proper current source R2 would have a larger value and at the right side of R2 a current would be drawn to ground so that a DC voltage develops across R2. That voltage is than compared (by the opamp) to the voltage across R1. Your circuit is probably working on the opamp's DC offset, so when you swap the opamp, you get a different current.

Comment: It's not clear what your circuit is supposed to do. Where is the load connected? How is the op-amp powered? Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and press **Save and Insert** when done that an editable schematic gets saved in your post. No need for a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image upload and no background grid.

Comment: Indeed.  I've updated the circuit.  With the resistor values shown, it still gives me max current of 16 mA and I still don't understand the math, but as I reduce R3, I get more current.   The circuit is to power hot pluggable devices that might short to ground.  A simple current limiting resistor drops the voltage too much, so I'm looking for a workaround.  ---just realized that I can build the circuit right front the Stack Exchange editor.  Next time.

Comment: Also, please stop asking about the "the maths" behind a circuit. Do circuits run on mathematics and formulas? Nope, they run on moving electrons, currents and voltages. So first understand what happens to the currents and voltages. Then we could use some simple formulas (often just Ohm's Law) to **describe that behavior in a formula**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Help explain the math behind this high-side current limiting circuit*

Through the action of negative feedback, the op-amp seeks to maintain the voltages at both its inputs at precisely the same value. Input +Vin is set by the the 3.3 volt supply and the resistor divider formed by R2 and R3. To make -Vin the same value (the aim of op-amp negative feedback), M1's resistance added to R4's resistance has to produce the same voltage at -Vin as that set at +Vin. So the op-amp manipulates the conductivity of M1 via the gate voltage until this happens (in microseconds normally).

Another way of looking at it is this; if M1's resistance added to R4's resistance equalled 3 kΩ, the circuit would become perfectly balanced (like a wheatstone bridge). This is because R1 and R2 are the same value. If R1 was only 3.6 Ω then the resistance of M1+R4 would have to equal 300 Ω to obtain perfect balance. It's the op-amp via negative feedback that drives M1's resistance to change and hence it produces the balance condition. Once the balance condition is obtained, there is no differential voltage input into the op-amp and, the circuit finds equilibrium.

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation.  After doing some more experiments, I can see that reducing R1 and R2 allows me to maintain a higher voltage for my load (R1 is acting as a current limiting resistor to the load), but it also seems to affect how well the circuit can precisely limit the current.  This must be related to the opamp I'm using?

Comment: *R1 is acting as a current limiting resistor* Yes but no it should not be. You're still not understanding how this circuit could work. R1 is a **sense resistor**, it should not limit the current, it creates a **voltage** so that the opamp "knows" the current and can compare it to the voltage across R2. In a proper current source the MOSFET would limit the current. There are plenty of tutorials and circuit explanations about current source circuits to be found, **study those!**

Comment: Right, sorry.  What I meant to say is that there is a voltage drop across R1.  So keeping R1 small gives me a higher voltage on my load.

Comment: @RobertJonkman - the voltage dropped across R1 **always** equals the voltage dropped across R2. That is what the op-amp ensures; it tries to keep both its input signal voltages precisely the same value. As pointed out by Bimpelrekkie, R1 is a sense resistor. In fact, so is R2. Are you familiar with a wheatsone bridge because that is what this circuit actually is but, the op-amp controls one of the resistors (the MOSFET).

Comment: I've reread the answers a couple of times and the second part of Andy's answer is very intuitive.